# Is a brain neuron the only physical object in existence which cannot be in quantum superposition (firing / not firing)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse

Is a brain neuron (actually even only my own neuron, not anybody else's) the only physical object in existence which cannot be in superposition (firing / not firing)?

We never experience any superposition in our thinking, and computing in our brain to function obviously needs neurons to fire/not fire in definitive way. Actually, superposition interacting with our neuron is by definition "measuring" and definitely collapse of wave function.

Comment: We also never experience any superposition in an average rock that we pick up from the ground.  Or, at least, we don't think we do.  What makes you think neurons are any different?  Is it just that we have two verb phrases, "fire" and "not fire?"  If so, a cannon would be in the same class as a neuron.

Comment: The other question would be does our brain truly "compute" in the most precise mathematical sense?  I don't believe its been popular to think that way for many decades unless one's particular opinion on morality depends on it.  If you can find someone who argues that we are computors, we can look into that particular individuals position on QM waveform collapse.

Comment: @CartAmon: there is nothing in physics preventing large objects, including rocks, to be in superposition of multiple states.  Scientists would be even really surprised, if there is any object, other then neuron, which cannot be in superposition of many states. Size limit is unlikely. Neuron, however, cannot be in superposition of fired and not-fired, because that would mean that measurement went without collapse of wave function.

Comment: Why is the neuron important for measurement?

Answer (score 2):

The neuron is not special in any way under quantum mechanics.  It operates like any other element of our universe.

When we talk about measurement in the way you are talking about it, we are talking about the effect of a measurement made by a classical observer.  That is an observe that obeys the laws of classical mechanics.  No statement is made as to what sort of thing might be a classical observer.  It is often inferred that we treat a human being as a classical observer, but that's just because its convenient.

The reason we never observe quantum superposition in our daily life is because the effects of such quantum strangeness are so far below the noise floor that it isn't even funny.  Unless we actively take the time to construct an experiment whose job is to observe these effects, they tend just not to matter.  If you used classical mechanics, you would be 99.9999999% correct, but that 0.000000001% can't be ignored when driving the argument to telelogical extremes.

Now what is true in QM is that neurons, like rocks, have enormously large state vectors, due to the large number of particles, and these state vectors mix rather quickly.  Due to the central limit theorem, the expected value of these large state vectors has an astonishingly small standard deviation -- far smaller than any measurement you will choose to take of said rock.

If you do statistical analyses on quantum systems interacting with a pool of particles with randomly distributed states, you find that the system "decoheres," entering a state that is less defined by the strangeness of superposition and more defined by the raw laws of large numbers.

Indeed, if you look at the experiments which demonstrate quantum mechanics, a great deal of effort is taken to keep the objects in coherency longer than might be normally observed, so that we can get into situations where the effects of QM matter more.

Of course, if one's philosophical position demands that human thought support classical logic *and* demands that human thought superpose upon the physics of the human brain *and* does not support the possibility that there might be randomness in human thought, one can get into a position where their philosophy puts them in a bind.  Teasing that position apart takes considerably more effort, as it is questionable whether it is consistent with the current best models of physics that we have.

Comment: If we put detector of particle which is in superposition of spin-up and spin-down to show red light when spin-up detected, and blue for spin-down, we know that we will never see both red and blue light. Neural firing(s) for "I see red" and different firing(s) for "I see blue" a mutually exclusive, from perspective of that brain. There is no conceivable experiment which would show us both lights, so that we can experience superposition even of our neural firings. Apart of that exclusiveness, *any* other object in the universe is "wave function", potentially superposition of multiple states.

Comment: Also note that neuron particles (billions) can be in superposition of many states, but what matters is firings of neurons, therefore emergent information processing (computing) is working with "collapsed", discrete firings. That single event, firing of neuron, which alters emergent computation, is not allowed to be wave function of multiple possibilities (brain computation going multiple different ways).

Comment: You seem confident that you know what "I see red" means, in terms of neural activity, and what "I see blue means," both in your head.  How do you distinguish between 100% "I see red" and a superposition of 0.9999999999999999999999 "I see red" plus 0.00000000000000000000001 "I see blue?"  Are you aware enough of your own mental patterns to tell the difference?  What about the difference between the above superposition and "100% red plus a beta particle streaking into your head at an inopportune moment causing an unpredictable (but classical) effect on a neuron?

Comment: (And, just for purposes of discourse, I'm going to pretend you said "I see red" and "I see green" and adjusted the detector setup accordingly.  We actually can sense red/blue according to the theory of [Opponent Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opponent_process), but red/green is considered "impossible," so its a better test for your experiment.  I'm also assuming that you are using a physicalist model, where mental states supervene on physical states.  If there is a metaphysical qualia of "red" which is not physical, it changes the story)

Comment: And, just to speed the conversation along a bit, why are you so certain that the human mind can compute, and how do you define "compute?"  I typically go to the definitions used by Turing and Church, but those involve infinities that are typically hard to map into physical states, so it seems highly unlikely that anything that supervenes on the brain can "compute" in that rigorous sense.  It almost certainly must fall short.

Answer (score 1):

No, neurons are not the only things which cause measurements/wavefunction collaps. Exactly how wavefunction collapse works is still a bit of an open question (and I'm not a specialist in QM myself so I don't know the fine details) but what scientist *do* generally agree on is that consciousness is not important for collapse. Consciousness can trigger a collapse but so can any object that is large enough.

A popular explanation$^\dagger$ is that when quantum systems interact with some large object they '[decohere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence)'. Decoherence means that certain superpositions become unstable in the sense that the probability of observing these decreases over time. In the end you are left with collapsed states.

Imagine you have some (macroscopic) measurement device which depends on the spin of a particle. The outcome of the measurement could be anything as longs as its macroscopic: moving a needle, activating an LED, killing a cat idk. At first the particle is in some general superposition of spin up and spin down. As it interacts with the device information about the spin leaks into the environment. Some atoms in the device get entangled with the spin of our particle. The state of these atoms now depends on the spin of the particle and vice versa. More and more atoms get entangled until it reaches a certain treshold. The superposition state becomes unstable and as a result the spin is either up or down. The rest of the entangled atoms collapse along with the spin. We don't know where this treshold lies and obviously it depends on the measurement device.

$^\dagger$ I'm oversimplifying things a bit here. Quantum decoherence doesn't solve the [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem) and there is still a lot of debate about how measurements actually take place. The different interpretations (Copenhagen, many worlds, etc) also give measurements a completely different shape.

Comment: My claim is not "neurons are the only things which cause collapse", my claim is "my own neurons are the only objects in the universe which can never, from my perspective, get into superposition of fired and not-fired"

Comment: @MirzaHadzic In accordance to my answer, your neurons are just objects just like any other neurons. Any classical object can never get into superposition. With classical I mean not showing QM effects. Mainstream QM doesn't put neurons on a pedestal. They are just a collection of particles although they are a very complex and beautiful collection.

Comment: According to current state of physics, any object can be in superposition, no matter how big. Already some experiments achieved quite large objects. By that same physics, act of measurement cause "wave function collapse" , which means that my neurons will fire in definitive way, never getting into superposition So, my point is that QM actually, by talking about "act of measurement", puts neurons on pedestal.

Comment: @MirzaHadzic QM does not give a special status to neutrons. “Act of measurement” is a synonym for “becomes entangled with”. Schrödinger cat is very clear about whether it is alive or dead, while to anyone and anything outside of the box it is still in a superposition of states.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me all your thoughts are in a superposition till you decide to say something or do something!

Does an electron know in which state it is before it is measured by the observer?

Does the cat know it's alive or dead in the box?

Furthermore as far as I know we are just now starting to understand how the brain works (through scans and mapping etc), so your question might be impossible to answer as of yet outside of a philosophical context.

Comment: Yes, for you, my thoughts are in superposition, but not *your* thoughts. I made that distinction in my post: only thing incapable of superposition is firing of *my* neuron. Other people's entire brain can be in superposition of many states, including "dead", "alive" and "never existed".

Comment: @MirzaHadzic Are you a [solipsist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism)?